# OpenJpa how to find length of string in JPQL

Tags: jpa, db2, openjpa

I am using 
length(ze.string)>2 in openJpa query. but i am getting

```
SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=CHAR_LENGTH;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.53.95 {prepstmnt 1776269692 SELECT t0.f1, t0.f2, t0.f3, t0.f4, t0.f5, t0.f6, t0.f7, t0.f8, t0.f9, t0.f10, t0.f11, t0.f12, t0.f13, t0.f14, t0.f15, t0.f16, t0.f17 FROM table t0 WHERE (t0.f1 = ? AND CHAR_LENGTH(?) > ? AND .....
```

In plain query when i do length operation i am getting record but using jpa its not working. I looked [Here](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_query.html) used size it doesn't work. and the field is varchar and db2. trying from past 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 requires use of the SQL function `LENGTH`, yet OpenJPA seems to be incorrectly converting your JPQL to use SQL function `CHAR_LENGTH` (hence the error message - not that DB2 gives out clear messages saying what is wrong, who knows what SQLCODE=-440 is without having to search!!). 
Raise a bug on your JPA provider.

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000818.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give more details about your entity, persistence.xml, and query to get to the bottom or this.  However, I do not see how OpenJPA would use CHAR_LENGTH instead of LENGTH for DB2.  Let me explain.  If you look at DBDictionary here:

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/openjpa/branches/2.2.x/openjpa-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/openjpa/jdbc/sql/DBDictionary.java?view=markup

You can see it defines something called "stringLengthFunction" as follows:

public String stringLengthFunction = "CHAR_LENGTH({0})";

This is the string length function which should be used for each individual dictionary (i.e. Database config).  However, for DB2, the AbstractDB2Dictionary, see here:

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/openjpa/branches/2.2.x/openjpa-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/openjpa/jdbc/sql/AbstractDB2Dictionary.java?view=markup

overrides this as follows:

stringLengthFunction = "LENGTH({0})";

Given this, for DB2, LENGTH should be used.  I took the following simple query:

"select me.id from MyEntity me where length(me.name)>2"

And executed it on OpenJPA using DB2, and I got this:

SELECT t0.ID FROM MYENTITY t0 WHERE (CAST(LENGTH(t0.ID) AS BIGINT) > CAST(? AS BIGINT))  [params=(long) 2]

Thanks,

Heath Thomann